# RIP Routing for subnets within the same class C network?

Tags: packet-tracer

I'm trying to setup a network with 3 subnets like this (mask is /26):

```
First 192.168.20.0-64
Second 192.168.20.65-128
Third 192.168.20.129-255
```

First, I'm just trying to connect the first 2 with fiber optics (checking how it works) instead of serial. The routers are connecting using the IPs 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2.

The issue is that after I setup RIP routing to 192.168.20.0 and 192.168.1.0 there won't be connection from 1 side to the other. Ping between the routers is fine.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: are you using ripv1 or ripv2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using RIPv1, RIPv1 uses classful routing so you won't be be able to use variable-length subnet mask (VLSM). Try RIPv2, which uses Classless Inter-Domain Routing.